# How to display the JSON value in a java servlet

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-3.0, servlet-listeners

> JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();

```
 jsonObj.put("name","raja");
```

Declare the jsonobject var(jsonObj) and gave value("name","raja") using above code.

```
 System.out.println(jsonObj.name);
```

Just print the name but it shows the error.

Comment: To get a value from json object, use jsonObject.get(key), so it should be jsonObject.get("name") in your example.

Comment: Add error details also

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
System.out.println(jsonObj.getString("name"));
```

Comment: System.out.println(jsonObj.get("name")); it works well. Thank u @Abhay Jain

Comment: yes it gets you the object but in your case you know the type of your object that is a string

Comment: how to exit the loop while running using  angular js.

Comment: this question you have to ask it in the tag angular not here. to exit a loop is simple add a boolean initialises the false and do your treatment when you want to exit changes this boolean has true (it's for a while loop) please specify which loop you use